# How to drop Default Constraint for all non-nullable columns of type 'bit'

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework-core, database-migration

After using 'SQL Server Migration Assistant For MySQL' (SSMA) I noticed it created Default Constraints for any [tinyint(1) (MYSQL)] that had a default of '1'. This in turn effected my database first scaffolding for Entity Framework Core.

The following warning is given when scaffolding:
`The column 'dbo.applicationcategory.IsSystem' would normally be mapped to a non-nullable bool property, but it has a default constraint. Such a column is mapped to a nullable bool property to allow a difference between setting the property to false and invoking the default constraint. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851278 for details.`

How can I remove default constraints for all columns of type 'bit' that are not nullable for a specific schema in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

A way to remove default constraints for all columns of type 'bit' that are not nullable for a specific schema in SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'ALTER TABLE [' + T.NAME + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + DC.NAME + '];' + CHAR(13)
FROM SYS.TABLES T
JOIN SYS.DEFAULT_CONSTRAINTS DC ON DC.PARENT_OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID
JOIN SYS.COLUMNS C ON C.OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID
    AND C.COLUMN_ID = DC.PARENT_COLUMN_ID
JOIN SYS.TYPES TYPES ON TYPES.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID = C.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID
JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS S ON S.SCHEMA_ID = T.SCHEMA_ID
    AND S.NAME = 'DBO'
WHERE C.IS_NULLABLE = 0
    AND TYPES.NAME = 'BIT'

SELECT @SQL
--UNCOMMENT BELOW WHEN YOU ARE SATISFIED WITH THE DYNAMIC SQL
--EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```